# C# - How convert integer to byte with permutation?

Tags: c#, integer, byte

I want convert integer to byte. If integer bigger than byte range{0,255} then counting from the start. I mean if integer = 260 then function return 5 or if int = 1120 then return 96 and so on.

Comment: Just cast it to byte: `byte b = (byte) yourInt;`

Comment: There is a discrepancy in the expected results for this question, so the question marked as a duplicate doesn't answer it sufficiently. The answer below addresses this discrepancy, so I have reopened this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
byte myByte = (byte)(myInt & 0xFF);
```

However, note that 260 will give 4 instead of five. (E.g. 255->valid, 256->0, 257->1, 258->2, 259->3, 260->4)

If you really want 260 to give 5, then you are probably looking for the remainder after dividing by 255. That can be calculated using:

```
byte myByte = (byte)(myInt % 255);
```

Comment: Is `byte myByte = (byte)(myInt & 0xFF);` any different from directly casting to `byte`?

Comment: If primitive operations are enforced to be unchecked, then there is no difference. However, if an overflow check occurs, values outside the range of byte will cause an exception.

Comment: Note that you could also use `byte myByte = unchecked((byte)myInt);`

Comment: Also note that `1120 % 255` is `100` whereas `1120 & 0xff` is `96`. There is a discrepancy in the OP's expected results which s/he will need to address - but this answer correctly states both possible solutions.